# Check whether a Panel is dragged inside tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF application in C# and there is a Table Layout Panel in the Form, and i am generating panels on run time, and i can drag drop them easily inside Table Layout panel, now i need to read the Table layout panel and check if there is any panel or not, how to do that process...

Comment: I solve it by my own..

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for checking if the tablelayoutpanel contains panel
                    else if (c != null && c is Panel){
                        foreach (Control control in c.Controls){
                            Console.Write(control.Text);
                            if (control is Label){
                                string s = control.BackColor.ToString();
                                Console.Write("\nLabel Colour is = "+s+"\

Comment: I love the fact that you tagged this non-question `wpf` and specifically mention WPF in your post, and yet none of this is related to WPF at all. You really have no idea what you're doing do you?

Comment: Its a Windows Form Application, Thanks for Correction, :) i am new to C#